# Can I implement iOS smart banner's navigational flow in expo managed workflow without deep linking?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, smartbanner

I went through the Expo docs and did other R&D on how to implement navigational flow of smart banner when user downloads the App and is navigated to the screen where he downloaded the App from.

It's confusing and all I can see is to having to implement deep linking. Is there another way on how to implement smart banner's navigational flow?

I tried it in testflight but the universal link I created worked. The smart banner has my app store's id so somehow it's taking me to the App store's App and not to the testflight App.